# Image does not remain on screen after executing for loop in pygame

Tags: python, loops, class, pygame, draw

I have been trying to modify the code from this [Tutorial](http://programarcadegames.com/python_examples/f.php?file=bullets.py) so that after a bullet **strikes** an enemy the `player.png` image is shown at position `x = 60` and `y = 48`. But the image does **not remain fixed**, it just appears and disappears. I don't know exactly where the wrong or missing element is in the code but I suspect that one of the causes is some misuse of my part of the `for` loop within the `draw_reaction` function.

**My [player.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj2Fu.jpg) image**

**My MWE code:**

```
import pygame
import random

# Define some colors
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)

# --- Classes


class Block(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the block. """
    def __init__(self, color):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 15])
        self.image.fill(color)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the Player. """

    def __init__(self):
        """ Set up the player on creation. """
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([20, 20])
        self.image.fill(RED)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        """ Update the player's position. """
        # Get the current mouse position. This returns the position
        # as a list of two numbers.
        pos = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        # Set the player x position to the mouse x position
        self.rect.x = pos[0]


class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    """ This class represents the bullet . """
    def __init__(self):
        # Call the parent class (Sprite) constructor
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([4, 10])
        self.image.fill(BLACK)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()

    def update(self):
        """ Move the bullet. """
        self.rect.y -= 3


# --- Create the window

# Initialize Pygame
pygame.init()

# Set the height and width of the screen
screen_width = 700
screen_height = 400
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([screen_width, screen_height])

# --- Sprite lists

# This is a list of every sprite. All blocks and the player block as well.
all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# List of each block in the game
block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# List of each bullet
bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group()

# --- Create the sprites

for i in range(0,1,2):
    # This represents a block
    block = Block(BLUE)

    # Set a random location for the block
    block.rect.x = random.randrange(screen_width)
    block.rect.y = random.randrange(350)

    # Add the block to the list of objects
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)

# Create a red player block
player = Player()
all_sprites_list.add(player)
player_image = pygame.image.load("player.png").convert() 
# Loop until the user clicks the close button.
done = False

# Used to manage how fast the screen updates
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

score = 0
player.rect.y = 370

# -------- Main Program Loop -----------
while not done:
    # --- Event Processing
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            # Fire a bullet if the user clicks the mouse button
            bullet = Bullet()
            # Set the bullet so it is where the player is
            bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x
            bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y
            # Add the bullet to the lists
            all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
            bullet_list.add(bullet)

    # --- Game logic

    # Call the update() method on all the sprites


    # Calculate mechanics for each bullet
    for bullet in bullet_list:

        # See if it hit a block
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)

        # For each block hit, remove the bullet and add to the score
        for block in block_hit_list:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
            score += 1
            print(score)

        # Remove the bullet if it flies up off the screen
        if bullet.rect.y < -10:
            bullet_list.remove(bullet)
            all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
    def draw_reaction():
        for bullet in bullet_list:
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
            for block in block_hit_list:
                screen.blit(player_image, [60, 48]) 
    all_sprites_list.update() 
    # --- Draw a frame

    # Clear the screen
    screen.fill(WHITE)
    draw_reaction()
    # Draw all the spites
    all_sprites_list.draw(screen)

    # Go ahead and update the screen with what we've drawn.
    pygame.display.flip()

    # --- Limit to 20 frames per second
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
```

**EDIT UPDATE:** The game has only one enemy that appears in a random place each time the game starts again.

**EDIT UPDATE 2:** I know that in most games after a collision the enemy is removed from the screen. This also happens in my code. But for a particular need of mine I need that, as an consequence, an image (player.png) remains fixed constantly after this bullet collision with the enemy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is caused by the `draw_reaction()` function only drawing the `player_image` during the absolute-time the bullet is colliding with a block.  So it shows the image for a single frame (One 60th of a second), but then on the next loop the collision is no longer occurring (the bullet is removed), so it is never drawn.

There are a number of ways around this, but I'm not sure of the *purpose* of showing this bitmap, so maybe they're not as helpful as they should be.

The easiest fix is to probably turn the player image into a sprite, and simply add it to the existing `all_sprites_list` when the bullet-hit triggers, and then take it away some time later (or how ever it should work).

```
class PlayerShip( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "player.png" ) #.convert() 
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = ( 60, 48 )
```

Then later on:

```
player_sprite = PlayerShip()
```

and

```
def draw_reaction():
    for bullet in bullet_list:
        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            # TODO: ensure it's not showing already
            all_sprites_list.add( player_sprite )      # add the player sprite 
            break                                      # only add once
```

EDIT: Code snippets updated based on comment

Comment: ThankXD! Your answer works! I just needed to remove `.convert ()` in `self.image = pygame.image.load ("player.png") .convert ()` as I was getting the following `pygame.error error: cannot convert without pygame.display initialized`. It also replaces `.append` in `all_sprites_list.append (player_sprite)` with `.add` getting `all_sprites_list.add player_sprite)` as I was getting the following `AttributeError error: 'Group' object has no attribute 'append' `at the moment after the collision occurred.

Comment: Ah - the spritegroup `.add` my apologies.