# Enemy Sprite is hit and disappears but is not fixed later if it was hit on the sides

Tags: function, class, pygame, sprite, collision-detection

I have a code solved for this issue [Image does not remain on screen after executing for loop in pygame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60067478/image-does-not-remain-on-screen-after-executing-for-loop-in-pygame). So I decided to put some **platforms** as a result of what I learned from **pygame**. I also decided to make the **cowboy** move to the right and left and go down to the bottom of the **screen**.

But when a collision occurs on the right or left side of the cowboy as shown in the **Diagram**, the `class PlayerShip` **is not executed as expected** in the **main loop** through the `def draw_reaction ()` function **because I do not see the image** of the **cowboy** represented by `player_sprite` fixed in position `(60, 48)`. It only works correctly if the cowboy **is hit from below**.

Assets

[missile.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IrOuJ.jpg)

[cowboy.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzXrb.jpg)

[police.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0DFmy.jpg)

**Diagram:**

```
|missile| <--<-- (is touched its right side by the missile)|cowboy| <--<-- direction

   ^
   |
   ^
   | 
(fire missile direction vertical)
   ^
   |
   d
   i
   r
   e
   c
   t
   i
   o
   n
```

**My MWE coding:**

```
import pygame
import random

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
PURPLE = (255, 0, 255)
GRAY = (128,128,128)
SCREEN_WIDTH = 800
SCREEN_HEIGHT = 600


class PlayerShip( pygame.sprite.Sprite ):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load( "cowboy.png" )
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK) 
        self.rect  = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.topleft = ( 60, 48 ) 
player_sprite = PlayerShip() 


class Platform(pygame.sprite.Sprite):


    def __init__(self, width, height):
        super().__init__()

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width, height])
        self.image.fill(GREEN)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


class MovingPlatform(Platform):

    change_x = 0
    change_y = 0

    boundary_top = 0
    boundary_bottom = 0
    boundary_left = 0
    boundary_right = 0

    player = None

    level = None

    def update(self):
        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player)
        if hit:

            if self.change_x < 0:
                self.player.rect.right = self.rect.left
            else:
                self.player.rect.left = self.rect.right

        self.rect.y += self.change_y


        hit = pygame.sprite.collide_rect(self, self.player)
        if hit:
            if self.change_y < 0:
                self.player.rect.bottom = self.rect.top
            else:
                self.player.rect.top = self.rect.bottom

        if self.rect.bottom > self.boundary_bottom or self.rect.top < self.boundary_top:
            self.change_y *= -1

        cur_pos = self.rect.x - self.level.world_shift
        if cur_pos < self.boundary_left or cur_pos > self.boundary_right:
            self.change_x *= -1


class Level(object):
    def __init__(self, player):
        self.platform_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.player = player

        self.background = None

        self.world_shift = 0
        self.level_limit = -1000

    def update(self):
        self.platform_list.update()
        self.enemy_list.update()

    def draw(self, screen):
        screen.fill(GRAY)

        self.platform_list.draw(screen)
        self.enemy_list.draw(screen)

    def shift_world(self, shift_x):
        self.world_shift += shift_x

        for platform in self.platform_list:
            platform.rect.x += shift_x

        for enemy in self.enemy_list:
            enemy.rect.x += shift_x

class Room(object):
    wall_list = None
    enemy_sprites = None

    def __init__(self):

        self.wall_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
        self.enemy_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()


class Level_01(Level):
    def __init__(self, player):
        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1500

        level = [[210, 70, 500, 500],
                 [210, 70, 800, 400],
                 [210, 70, 1000, 500],
                 [210, 70, 1120, 280],
                 [210, 70, -120, 500],
                 ]

        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)


        block = MovingPlatform(70, 40)
        block.rect.x = 1350
        block.rect.y = 280
        block.boundary_left = 1350
        block.boundary_right = 1600
        block.change_x = 10
        block.player = self.player
        block.level = self
        self.platform_list.add(block)



class Level_02(Level):


    def __init__(self, player):



        Level.__init__(self, player)

        self.level_limit = -1000


        level = [[210, 70, 500, 550],
                 [210, 70, 800, 400],
                 [210, 70, 1000, 500],
                 [210, 70, 1120, 280],
                 ]


        for platform in level:
            block = Platform(platform[0], platform[1])
            block.rect.x = platform[2]
            block.rect.y = platform[3]
            block.player = self.player
            self.platform_list.add(block)


        block = MovingPlatform(70, 70)
        block.rect.x = 1500
        block.rect.y = 300
        block.boundary_top = 100
        block.boundary_bottom = 550
        block.change_y = -1
        block.player = self.player
        block.level = self
        self.platform_list.add(block)




class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        width = 40
        height = 60
        self.image = pygame.image.load("police.png").convert()

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK) 


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()


        self.change_x = 0
        self.change_y = 0


        self.level = None

    def update(self):
        self.calc_grav()

        self.rect.x += self.change_x

        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:
            if self.change_x > 0:
                self.rect.right = block.rect.left
            elif self.change_x < 0:

                self.rect.left = block.rect.right
        self.change_y += 0


        self.rect.y += self.change_y


        block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        for block in block_hit_list:


            if self.change_y > 0:
                self.rect.bottom = block.rect.top
            elif self.change_y < 0:
                self.rect.top = block.rect.bottom


            self.change_y = 0

            if isinstance(block, MovingPlatform):
                self.rect.x += block.change_x

    def calc_grav(self):

        if self.change_y == 0:
            self.change_y = 1
        else:
            self.change_y += .35


        if self.rect.y >= SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height and self.change_y >= 0:
            self.change_y = 0
            self.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - self.rect.height

    def jump(self):


        self.rect.y += 2
        platform_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self, self.level.platform_list, False)
        self.rect.y -= 2


        if len(platform_hit_list) > 0 or self.rect.bottom >= SCREEN_HEIGHT:
            self.change_y = -10


    def go_left(self):

        self.change_x = -6

    def go_right(self):

        self.change_x = 6

    def stop(self):

        self.change_x = 0
class Cowboy(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.image = pygame.image.load("cowboy.png").convert()
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
          self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK) 

class Missile(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
      def __init__(self):
          super().__init__()
          self.image = pygame.image.load("missile.png").convert()
          self.image.set_colorkey(BLACK) 
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
      def update(self):
         self.rect.y += -3

def main():
    pygame.init()


    size = [SCREEN_WIDTH, SCREEN_HEIGHT]
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    block_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    all_sprites_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    bullet_list = pygame.sprite.Group() 
    pygame.display.set_caption("Platformer with moving platforms")
    apple = pygame.image.load("missile.png").convert()
    block = Cowboy()
    player_image = pygame.image.load("cowboy.png").convert()


    player = Player()


    level_list = []
    level_list.append(Level_01(player))
    level_list.append(Level_02(player))


    current_level_no = 0
    current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
    block_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(block)
    all_sprites_list.add(player)

    active_sprite_list = pygame.sprite.Group()
    player.level = current_level

    player.rect.x = 340
    player.rect.y = SCREEN_HEIGHT - player.rect.height
    active_sprite_list.add(player)


    done = False


    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    x_speed = 0
    y_speed = 0

    rect_x = 50
    rect_y = 50
    rect_change_x = 1
    rect_change_y = 90
    x = rect_x

    y = rect_y
    player.rect.y = rect_x

    player.rect.y = 480
    score = 0
    size = (1366, 768)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.RESIZABLE) 
    while not done:
        x += x_speed
        y += y_speed
        rect_x += rect_change_x

        if rect_x > 280:
           rect_change_x *= -1
           rect_x += rect_change_x
           rect_y += rect_change_y
        if rect_x < 0:
           rect_change_x *= -1
           rect_x += rect_change_x
           rect_y += rect_change_y       

        block.rect.x = rect_x
        block.rect.y = rect_y



        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                done = True

            elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:

                bullet = Missile()

                bullet.rect.x = player.rect.x
                bullet.rect.y = player.rect.y

                all_sprites_list.add(bullet)
                bullet_list.add(bullet)

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                    player.go_left()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                    player.go_right()
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                    player.jump()

            if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and player.change_x < 0:
                    player.stop()
                if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and player.change_x > 0:
                    player.stop()

        for bullet in bullet_list:
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
            for block in block_hit_list:
                bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
                score += 1
                print(score)
                screen.blit(player_image, [60, 48]) 
            if bullet.rect.y < -10:
               bullet_list.remove(bullet)
               all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        def draw_reaction():
            for bullet in bullet_list:
                block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
                for block in block_hit_list:
                    all_sprites_list.add( player_sprite )
                    break
        all_sprites_list.update()

        active_sprite_list.update()


        current_level.update()


        if player.rect.right >= 1500:
            diff = player.rect.right - 500
            player.rect.right = 500
            current_level.shift_world(-diff)


        if player.rect.left <= 120: 
            diff = 120 - player.rect.left 
            player.rect.left = 120 
            current_level.shift_world(diff)


        current_position = player.rect.x + current_level.world_shift
        if current_position < current_level.level_limit:
            if current_level_no < len(level_list)-1:
                player.rect.x = 120
                current_level_no += 1
                current_level = level_list[current_level_no]
                player.level = current_level
            else:
                done = True


        current_level.draw(screen)
        active_sprite_list.draw(screen)
        x += x_speed
        y += y_speed
        all_sprites_list.draw(screen)
        draw_reaction()




        clock.tick(60)


        pygame.display.flip()

    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**UPDATE EDIT:** If `current_level.draw(screen)` is not used in the main loop then the code works as expected. But I still don't know what causes it.

Answer (score 0):

I simply added `all_sprites_list.add (player_sprite)` to the `for block in block_hit_list:`. In my view this would be necessary to track `self.image.get_rect ()`.  Then:

Before:

```
for bullet in bullet_list:
    block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
    for block in block_hit_list:
        bullet_list.remove(bullet)
        all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
        score += 1
        print(score)
        screen.blit(player_image, [60, 48]) 
    if bullet.rect.y < -10:
       bullet_list.remove(bullet)
       all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
```

Later:

```
for bullet in bullet_list:
            block_hit_list = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(bullet, block_list, True)
            for block in block_hit_list:
                all_sprites_list.add(player_sprite)     
                bullet_list.remove(bullet)
                all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
                score += 1
                print(score)
                screen.blit(player_image, [60, 48]) 
            if bullet.rect.y < -10:
               bullet_list.remove(bullet)
               all_sprites_list.remove(bullet)
```

But I would like someone to explain to me how it really happened behind the code by making more experienced references to the documentation or the style of the code itself. Thankful if anyone can make that explanation.